# WinPcap installation error

Tags: windows, networking, sniffing, winpcap

When installing WinPcap 4.1.2 (as well as earlier versions) I get the following error:

> An error occurred while loading the WinPcap Install Helper DLL

I checked the [WinPcap FAQ](http://www.winpcap.org/misc/faq.htm) but there was nothing relevant.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [problem](http://www.winpcap.org/pipermail/winpcap-bugs/2010-October/001296.html) occurs if you've installed update KB2264107.

You need to [modify your registry to add a CWDIllegalInDllSearch entry](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2264107) for the WinPcap installer.

Create a .reg file with the following contents:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\WinPcap_4_1_2.exe]
"CWDIllegalInDllSearch"=dword:00000000
```

And merge it (make sure the name/version number of the .exe matches the name of the WinPcap installer).
Now re-run the install and everything is hunky-dory.